# Panel Data with time gap, How to create lag variable

Tags: panel, stata, lag

I am dealing with panel data with a time gap. but not the same time gap.
`Year` variable has 1980, 1990, 2000, 2010, 2015, and 2020.

As you can see it has a 10 year time gap up to 2010, but five-years between 2010 and 2020.

After setting up for panel data structure in Stata (using `xtset` command), I wanted to use the time (lag) operator for my main variable interest and outcome variable. However, when I use `L.` in front of the variable name, Stata tells me `no observations`.

Isn't it automatically taking the previous time period?

Or do I create manually the lag variables?

Comment: You do not show any code, which is puzzling in a programming forum. `help xtset` does document `delta()` which is your main way to make progress here. Lack of research and clarity led me to downvote.

Answer (score 1):

What we need to know, but can't see, is exactly what code you used, specifically `xtset`. But it's possible to guess. Here I fabricate one panel; a structure with more panels doesn't show different problems.

```
clear 
input Y Year 
1  1980
2  1990 
3  2000 
4  2010  
5  2015 
6  2020 
end 

gen ID = 42
```

If you just specify panel and year variables, Stata expects unit spacing, so lag 1 with yearly data means "the previous year". Asking for a lag 1 variable is legal, but all values are missing.

```
xtset ID Year 
gen lag1 = L1.Y
```

If you specify `delta(5)` then a lag 1 variable is missing in all but two observations.

```
xtset ID Year, delta(5) 
gen lag5 = L1.Y
```

If you try `delta(10)` that won't work (unless you `drop` 2015).

```
xtset ID Year, delta(10)
```

You can also do this:

```
bysort ID (Year) : gen prev = Y[_n-1]
```

Bringing your results together

```
list , sep(0) 

     +------------------------------------+
     | Y   Year   ID   lag1   lag5   prev |
     |------------------------------------|
  1. | 1   1980   42      .      .      . |
  2. | 2   1990   42      .      .      1 |
  3. | 3   2000   42      .      .      2 |
  4. | 4   2010   42      .      .      3 |
  5. | 5   2015   42      .      4      4 |
  6. | 6   2020   42      .      5      5 |
     +------------------------------------+
```

The `no observations` error message presumably comes from some other command.